# Why do modern sites frequently use JSON blobs client-side and construct the webpage in JavaScript client-side?

Tags: website-design, design, site-structure

I have noticed something in later years. Instead of actually creating a HTML page, such as a table of data, on the server and sending the finished HTML page, they nowadays send a "minimal" (in a very *broad* sense of that word...) webpage which executes a JavaScript which in turn loads in JSON blobs which it then parses in JavaScript, client-side, to construct a webpage which is finally displayed to the user.

One side-effect of this, intentional or not, is that it often makes it much easier for me to "grab" their data since they frequently just "dump" their internal database's fields to the client, even if they themselves don't use all fields. So in a way, it's like they are making it easier for people like me to automate things on their websites, whereas I used to have to constantly parse complex, messy, ever-changing HTML code.

So while I hate how idiotic this is from a logical/user perspective, as well as from a security one (depending on various factors), it's actually "good" for me in a way. I just don't *understand* it, since it's significantly more work on their part and an overall extremely *strange* way of doing things.

Whenever I notice that a HTML page is "empty from content", I always open the network tab in Pale Moon and reload the page, and then I see a "JSON" blob which I can study. It's bizarre. It's almost as if they are unofficially providing an "API" without mentioning it openly, but secretly they wink/nudge to us "powerusers"?

Comment: It may have something to do with the popularity of frameworks like Angular and React.